# Make a t chart for $f(x) = -3^x$

Tags: calculus

I am bit confused. I don't know if it is my calculations but when $f(x)=-3^x$, I get $f(-2)=\frac19$.
That can't be right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that $a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$ for all $a,b$.

Next, there is a difference between $-3^x$ and $(-3)^x$ that you should be aware of. I will illustrate the difference for $x=-2$:

$$-3^x = -(3^x) = -(3^{-2}) = -\frac{1}{3^2} = \frac{-1}{9}$$

$$(-3)^x = (-3)^{-2} = \frac{1}{(-3)^2} = \frac{1}{9}$$

Hopefully this clears up your confusion regarding what *must* be wrong. Maybe you've calculated as if there were parentheses when in fact there are none, or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that this is $-3^{x}=(-1)\cdot3^{x}$ not $(-3)^{x}$. So $f(-2)=-(3^{-2})$.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)=-(3)^x \Rightarrow f(-2)=-(3)^{-2}=-\frac{1}{3^{2}}=-\frac{1}{9}$.

For $f(x)=(-3)^x \Rightarrow f(-2)=(-3)^{-2}=\frac{1}{(-3)^2}=\frac{1}{9}$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which operation do you apply first (exponentiation or negation). For exponentiation $\to$ negation, you will get $-\frac{1}{9}$, and for negation $\to$ exponentiation, you will get $\frac{1}{9}$.